# Мне нужно отправить сообщение через интернет

Tags: c++, сетевое-программирование

Пробовал так:

```
#define PORT xxxxx
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int Client() {
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    int sock = 0, value;
    const char* helloclient = "Client Hello";
    char buffer[1024] = { 0 };

    // инициализация библиотеки Winsock
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize Winsock" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // создаём сокет
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // настраиваем объект сокета
    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // форматируем IP-адрес в бинарный формат
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", &server_addr.sin_addr);

    // подсоединяемся к серверу
    connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*) & server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));

    // отсылаем сообщение серверу
    send(sock, helloclient, strlen(helloclient), 0);

    // читаем ответ от сервера
    value = recv(sock, buffer, 1024, 0);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    // закрываем сокет
    closesocket(sock);

    // выгружаем библиотеку Winsock
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    Client();
    return 0;
}
```

Но так получается отправить сообщение только для компьютеров в одной сети. А если компьютер находится в сети интернет, то ничего не работает.

Однако у меня есть своя страница в интернете. Может, получится передать сообщение хотя бы на этот хостинг, но как?

Comment: А у вас на хостинге фаерволл есть? Если да, то поговорите с ним. Тем более вы не можете передать сообщение туда, где его не ждут. На хостинге нужно: раз - поднять сервер, который будет слушать входящие сообщения, два - разрешить доступ извне к порту на котором работает сервер (к примечанию о фаерволле выше)

Comment: Потому и существует Клиент-Серверные приложения. Т.е. сообщения для клиентов проходят Сервер, где он передает сообщение, тому кто подключен к серверу. Для выхода в интернет, ваш провайдер выделяет айпи адрес, который используют многие пользователи, сети провайдера. И естественно у провайдера есть сервер, который всё это распределяет. Зайдя к примеру на Яндекс.Интернетометр можно увидеть ваш IP. Который отличается от IP сети провайдера и IP в сети роутера :) И если знаете IP пользователя внутри сети провайдера, то введите в CMD / tracert IP. Увидите путь к вашему теоретическому получателю :)

Comment: Взял всё вами сказанное на заметку. От себя хочу добавить, что загорелся идеей отправить по FTP именно потому, что на своём уровне я не смогу написать программу, использующую данные из tracert. Отсюда желание попробовать через вебсайт. Хостинг даёт возможность передавать файлы через FileZilla на порт 21 с логином и паролем. Есть код для такого случая, но мне требуется установить библиотеку, которую я всё никак не могу установить (libcurl).

Comment: Ну то есть по сути, вы хотите создать свой сервер? И предоставлять доступ к данным. Делают и на домашнем компе, но клиентам нужно сообщать свой IP адрес. У провайдера можно купить "белый IP". Не знаю как сейчас, раньше это стоило дешевле чем сервер в инете.  В общем почитайте еще информации и примите решение :) А может Яндекс диск" вам подойдет. Там примерно тоже о чем вы мечтаете, только беЗплатно ;)

Comment: Да, свой сервер, который будет в конце концов доступен клиентам. Для Яндекс Диска ведь нужно ещё знать его API, суметь им воспользоваться? Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Для случая с FTP:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main() {
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
FILE *file;

// Инициализация библиотеки libcurl
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

// Создание объекта CURL
curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
// Установка URL-адреса FTP-сервера
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, 
"ftp://example.com/path/to/destination/file.txt");

// Установка имени пользователя и пароля для авторизации на FTP-сервере
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "username");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "password");

// Установка опции для загрузки файла
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);

// Открытие локального файла
fopen_s(&file, "local_file.txt", "rb");
if(file) {
// Установка пути к локальному файлу
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, file);

// Выполнение запроса
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
if(res != CURLE_OK) {
fprintf(stderr, "Ошибка при отправке файла: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
}

// Закрытие локального файла
fclose(file);
} else {
fprintf(stderr, "Не удалось открыть локальный файл\n");
}
```

// Освобождение ресурсов
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}

```
// Освобождение глобальных ресурсов libcurl
curl_global_cleanup();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: И все равно вам где-то нужно разместить ссылку на файл? С таким же успехом можно ссылку на Яндекс.Диск разместить. Там без FTP, HTTP скачка файлов происходит, что удобнее и не нужен FTP клиент.